# How can I make an Index that simulates an inner join with RavenDB 3.5?

Tags: c#, nosql, ravendb

I've searched the internet and every potential answer to my question is either not in C# or not available with my RavenDB version.

I want to do the simpliest inner join on 2 different document types. (I know it's a document based DB and not a relational one but I'm not responsible for the current modelisation)

Let's say I have these 2 different document types:

```
public class FirstDocumentType
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstDocumentTypeProperty { get; set; }

    public string SecondDocumentTypeId { get; set; }
}

public class SecondDocumentType
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string SecondDocumentProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I want an index that returns something like this:

```
public class IndexResult
{
    public string FirstDocumentTypeId { get; set; }

    public string SecondDocumentTypeId { get; set; }

    public string FirstDocumentTypeProperty { get; set; }

    public string SecondDocumentProperty { get; set; }
}
```

How do I do that with c#?

For RavenDB version 3.x prior to 3.5 I know it was possible to do that with a transform result within an Index constructor with something like this:

```
          TransformResults =
                (database, firstDocumentTypes) => from firstDocumentType in firstDocumentTypes
                    let secondDocumentType = database.Load<SecondDocumentType>(firstDocumentType.SecondDocumentTypeId)
                    select new
                    { 
                        FirstDocumentTypeId = firstDocumentType.Id,
                        SecondDocumentTypeId = secondDocumentType.Id,
                        firstDocumentType.FirstDocumentTypeProperty,
                        secondDocumentType.SecondDocumentProperty 
                    };
```

Now in version 3.5 the transformer needs to be in a class on it's own and I can't seem to find how to use the database to fetch the SecondDocumentType from it's id within the FirstDocumentType. The delegate function only takes 1 argument which is the document type.

EDIT: I've actually found my answer in the documentation https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/csharp/transformers/loading-documents

I just have a hard time navigating in it...

Comment: If you can upgrade to RavenDB 4.2 or 5.0 then you can follow the example in:  https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/related-documents/index-related-documents,    
which demonstrates how to **index a related document**.

Comment: Thanks but no I can't... not now anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone wondering there is a function called "LoadDocument" available in AbstractTransformerCreationTask.

It can be used to simulate the INNER JOIN. Simple as that...

I've actually found my answer in the documentation https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/csharp/transformers/loading-documents

I just have a hard time navigating in it...

Answer (score 2):

I think the syntax that you are looking for can be found in this tests repository:

https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/v3.5/Raven.Tests/Indexes/TransformerParameterTest.cs

Comment: Just to be clear, this is not want I'm asking for but It's good to know anyway. I was only trying to do an INNER JOIN and the "LoadDocument" of the AbstractTransformerCreationTask class is there for that. I just didn't see the function the first time I looked for some reason.